# Add download links to toctree

Tags: python, python-sphinx, toctree

I would like to add a bulleted list of download links within my toctree.

Ideally, it would look something like this:

- [Foo Example](/#)

  - **download foo.py file**
  - **download foo.ipynb file**
- [Bar Example](/#)

  - **download bar.py file**
  - **download bar.ipynb file**

I've tried:

```
.. toctree::

   foo
   * :download:`download foo.py file <files/foo.py>`
   * :download:`download foo.ipynb file <files/foo.ipynb>`
   bar
   * :download:`download bar.py file <files/bar.py>`
   * :download:`download bar.ipynb file <files/bar.ipynb>`
```

But this fails since `toctree` only expects references to documents:

```
WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document '* :download:`download foo.py file <files/foo.py>`'
```

The closest I've come is:

```
.. toctree::

   foo
   
* :download:`download foo.py file <files/foo.py>`
* :download:`download foo.ipynb file <files/foo.ipynb>`

.. toctree::

   bar

* :download:`download bar.py file <files/bar.py>`
* :download:`download bar.ipynb file <files/bar.ipynb>`
```

Which looks about like this:

- [Foo Example](/#)
- **download foo.py file**
- **download foo.ipynb file**
- [Bar Example](/#)
- **download bar.py file**
- **download bar.ipynb file**

This does not look great and I have many more documents in my actual `toctree`. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downloads are not reStructuredText documents, and cannot be entries in a toctree.

Instead you have two workarounds.

1. Use a fully qualified HTTP URL to the download.

   ```
   .. toctree::

       https://helloworld.com/src/helloworld.py
   ```
2. Create an intermediary `.rst` document that contains a link to the download, and put that document in your toctree.

Comment: Makes sense. I did not know about the fully qualified HTTP URL option. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt I fingered it out by careful reading of the [`toctree` docs](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-toctree): "You can also add external links, by giving an HTTP URL instead of a document name."